# Do we have $\int_{0}^x \frac{t^N}{1-t} dt \to 0$ if $N \to \infty$ and $1 \leq x < 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Do we have $\int_{0}^x \frac{t^N}{1-t} dt \to 0$ if $N \to \infty$ and $1 \leq x < 1$?

I think that we have
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^x \frac{t^N}{1-t} dt \\
& = \int_{0}^x \frac{1}{1-t} d(\frac{t^{N+1}}{N+1}) \\
& = \frac{t^{N+1}}{(N+1)(1-t)}\big|_{0}^x + \int_0^x \frac{t^{N+1}}{N+1} d(\frac{1}{1-t}).
\end{align}
But it seems that the integral is not simplified. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does $1 \le x < 1$ even make sense? A possible way to do it might be to write $\frac{1}{1-t}$ as $\sum_{n} t^{n}$.

Comment: I assume you mean $0\leq x <1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to actually evaluate the integral exactly to show it goes to $0$; you can just bound it above.  Fix an $x$ such that $0\leq x<1$ (I assume this is what you meant), and write $I_N=\int_{0}^x \frac{t^N}{1-t} dt$.  Since $t^N\leq x^N$ and $1-t\geq 1-x$ for all $t\in[0,x]$, $$0\leq I_N\leq \int_{0}^x \frac{x^N}{1-x} dt=\frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x}.$$

Since $1-x$ doesn't depend on $N$ and $x^{N+1}\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, we conclude that $\frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x}\to 0$ as $N\to \infty$, and hence by the inequality above $I_N\to 0$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac{t^N}{1-t}\ dt&=\int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t}\ dt
-\int_0^x \frac{1-t^N}{1-t}\ dt\\
&=\ln(1-x)-\int_0^x \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}t^k\ dt\\
&=\ln(1-x)-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_0^x t^k\ dt\\
&=\ln(1-x)-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\\
&=\ln(1-x)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{x^{k}}{k}\\
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^x \frac{t^N}{1-t}\ dt&=\ln(1-x)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}\\
&=\ln(1-x)-\ln(1-x)\\
&=0
\end{align}